# IRC bot: MOTD doesn't come even though I did USER and NICK

Tags: python, version, irc, bots

I'm making an IRC bot in python for the hackthissite challenge (prog 8).
Here's an excerpt of the connection code:

```
def ping():
    ircsock.send("PONG :Pong\n")
ircsock.connect((server,6667))
ircsock.send("USER "+botnick+" "+server+" "+botnick+" :"+version+"\n")
ircsock.send("NICK "+botnick+"\n")
while(connect):
    ircmsg = ircsock.recv(2048)
    ircmsg = ircmsg.strip('\n\r')
    print(ircmsg)
    if(ircmsg.find("PING :") != -1):
        ping()
```

I don't think that there's anything wrong with this.
All variables are defined and have a value, this code works without a problem on some servers (freenode for example). But on other servers (foonetic, hackthissite) I get the following output:

```
:hub.irc.hackthissite.org NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname...
:hub.irc.hackthissite.org NOTICE AUTH :*** Found your hostname
PING :3C8E9173
:3C8E9173!nospoof@hub.irc.hackthissite.org PRIVMSG Tadbot :VERSION
```

I'm not sure what to do with this. I have tried sending back the version of my bot to the username between the ":" and the "!", which (as expected) didn't do anything. On servers where this happens, I never get my MOTD so I get the "You have not registered" error when I try to do anything.

Google yielded some results of people explaining similar problems, but it'd always be that they forgot to send their USER and NICK, so I'm really at a loss about what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must send the `PONG` response to the server's `PING`, otherwise the server will think the connection is dead.

The correct reply in the example you posted would be

```
PONG :3C8E9173
```

3C8E9173 being the same string as the server requested.

Comment: The correct syntax would be to imitate the server. In which case, your best bet would be to whip up mIRC in debug mode (`/debug @debug`) and connect to a server, you'll see the communication between the server and the client clearly.

Comment: I've made a working IRC bot (only in PHP) would you like me to arrange the source files for you? It's OOP based and not complete, but the server/client communication is flawless.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Truth's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8772194/134633), the `VERSION` message is a CTCP message.  This is indicated by the payload of the `PRIVMSG` being surrounded by unprintable ASCII `\001` (CTRL-A) characters; it is actually `\001VERSION\001`.

To reply to it, you need to send a `PRIVMSG` back to the source nick also formatted as a CTCP message: eg. `\001VERSION Nyubis Python Bot\001`.